# Generating .crt and .key file to setup SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, cryptography, wamp

We have a an SSL certificate purchased from godaddy and following are the files we have received while downloading the certificate

1. a4dab126b74b0e92.crt
2. gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

We have the domain hosted at our own machine and not with godaddy.

By looking into the ssl conf file in apache it seems that we need three files to install the cert on the server.

1. SSLCertificateFile (server.crt)
2. SSLCertificateKeyFile (server.key)
3. SSLCertificateChainFile (ca.crt)

I would like to know how to generate these files and what the downloaded files stand for.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: The `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` can likely be used as the `ca.crt`, your purchased certificate (I assume `a4dab126b74b0e92.crt`) would be `server.crt`, and the key you used to generate the original certificate request would become the `server.key`.

Comment: csr was generated using IIS and hence no key is with me.Can I install the cert and export as a pfx file and then extract the key?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the most straightforward option.